# how to read attribute in line of file XML use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am trying to read attribute of line in file xml using jquery.

this is my xml:

```
       <?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <biology>
        <item>
            <image type="test">cafroost.gif</image>
            <sound>cafroost.wav</sound>
            <name>cà rốt</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <image type="write">cafroost.gif</image>
            <sound>cafroost.wav</sound>
            <name>cà rốt</name>
        </item>
       </biology>
```

This is my code to read file xml:

```
$("#ajaxButton").click(function(){
          $.get('js/data.xml', function(xml){
                var biology = $.xml2json(xml);
                len = biology.item.length;
                alert(biology.item[0].image);
            })
      });
```

I try to read attribute "type" like:

```
alert(biology.item[0].image.attr("type"));
```

But it's not work. Anyone know how to do read that attribute??

I am newbie. Please help me.

thanks for reading.!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
var type = biology.find('item > image').eq(0).attr('type')
```

Comment: Actualy my XML file have a lot <item> tag, and that line not work. :(

Comment: i try "var type = biology.find('item[' + 1 + '] > image').attr('type');" and "var type = biology.find('item[1] > image').attr('type');" and some kind of index and this is still return "object #<object> has no method 'find'"